# Batch file - Current working directory interferes with environment variable CD

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables, cwd

on my Windows laptop my company sets the environment variable CD to some directory and I can not change that. In a batch file I have to use the current working directory like

```
set current_dir=%cd%
```

Now the environment overrides the current directory. If I put the line

```
set cd=
```

in front the original variable would be deleted. Is there a safe way to get the current directory as the batch file might be used in other environments too?

Comment: `%cd%` is a system variable. Don't touch it.

Comment: My company sets the variable and Windows permits it. That's why I am asking for a safe solution.

Comment: What is the output of `Echo(%__CD__%` and/or `Echo(%__CD__:~,-1%`?

Comment: You must say your company that `%cd%` variable must not be set never and that they should change their Batch files. If you set `%time%` variable you can not get the time, although in this case it can be retrieved by other means. If you set `%errorlevel%` variable you can _not_ get this value in any other way... In other words: dynamic system variables must _not_ be set. You must not set it and then look for a patch/solution for this problem... **`:(`** Anyway, this is a possible solution: `( set "cd=" & set "current_dir=!cd!" & set "cd=%cd%" )`

Comment: @RaphaelM. I see you are new around here... I have given the solution to your problem. If you don't have administrative privileges to edit the Windows registry, you can still enter `DOSKEY` manually or create a batch-file with `DOSKEY`. Either way it will work and you will get your `%CD%` back. However, please consider voting on the answer and marking it as resolved. You get 2 points doing this. ;)

Comment: @Compo `%__CD__%` instead of `%CD%` is just what I need. @Mofi was right. I confused the current working directory with the directory containing the batch file. I will also try to convince our company to switch to another environment variable.

Comment: What would you do if your company decides to also use `%__CD__%` variable? **`;)`**

Comment: @Aacini I tried to set `__CD__`. It is not possible.
After `C:\>set __CD__=test`
the command
`C:\>echo %__CD__%`
returns
`C:\ `

Comment: First of all, this was just a joke! **`:)`** Anyway, this is strange. the `set __CD__=test` command _DO_ define the `__CD__` variable. You can confirm that via `set _` command. However, if you try to access the variable value via expansion: `%__CD__%` or `!__CD__!` then the environment variable is _ignored_ and the internal value is returned... As I said, this is strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I'd suggest, for general use, as per my comment, is that you use `%__CD__%`, *(or if you do not want the trailing backward slash, `%__CD__:~,-1%`)*, instead.

Example:

```sh
@Set "CWD=%__CD__:~,-1%"
@Set CWD 2>NUL
@Pause
```

The following alternatives may also help you out, although none are tested within a similarly broken environment:

```sh
@Set "CWD="
@For %%G In (.) Do @Set "CWD=%%~fG"
@Set CWD 2>NUL
@Pause
```

```sh
@Set "CWD="
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('CD') Do @Set "CWD=%%G"
@Set CWD 2>NUL
@Pause
```

```sh
@Set "CWD="
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Echo Prompt $P^|%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D/E')Do @Set "CWD=%%G"
@Set CWD 2>NUL
@Pause
```

Answer (score -1):

The basic command to assign the current path to a variable is this:

| Command line: | <kbd>`FOR /f %p in ('CD') do SET myVar=%p`</kbd> |
| --- | --- |
| Batch script: | <kbd>`FOR /f %%p in ('CD') do SET myVar=%%p`</kbd> |

---

But you can go further and edit the Windows registry 
<kbd>`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor]\autoron`</kbd> 
by inserting the following macro every time you open an instance of MSDOS:

```
DOSKEY CHDIR=(IF [$1] == [] ( CD ) ELSE ( PUSHD $* )) & FOR /f %p in ('CD') do @SET cd=%p
```

Thus, overriding the `CHDIR` command to set the current path to the `%cd%` variable or whatever else you want. Also working with network directories :D

Comment: What is the advantage of the doskey approach instead of deleting the environment variable via `set cd=`?

Comment: Your company has redefined the `%CD%` variable, so it will never be overwritten again when you run the `CD` command. The advantage of defining a macro is that you don't need to `SET cd=` variable every time you need it. Just run the `CHDIR` macro yourself and it will update the variable for you. Note that `CD` is an alias for `CHDIR`, what I've done is overwrite the pre-existing `CHDIR` command so it no longer respects your company definition, and go back to updating the variable. You can switch to `CD` if you like.

Comment: As I said in my question I do not want to touch the environment variable `CD`. This may have other side effects on my system and a macro is too much hassle anyway. The first part of your answer is more what I was looking for and similar to the solution from @Compo. But thank you for your efforts!

Comment: ??? Just change the name of the variable that will receive the path. I gave you the best solution in the world and you spat on the plate.